# Xcode 13.2.1 iOS 16.0 Device Support Files Not Working

Tags: xcode, ios16

Today updated my iPhone to iOS 16.0, had device support files for 16.0 installed from known depository on GitHub (i.e. https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport), and then tried to build from Xcode 13.2.1, but still no support for iOS 16.0. Previously, the trick was working with 15.5 and 15.6, but not today with 16.0. Is there something wrong with 16.0 files? They seem to be about 3 month old. Have anyone seen this issue and found the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Issue resolved, thanks to [XCode does not show my iPhone as a destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73711213/xcode-does-not-show-my-iphone-as-a-destination)

Apparently, starting with iOS 16.0, the device needs to be placed in the Developer Mode. Summarizing the steps that were working for iOS 15.X, if you are using an old Xcode version, i.e. 13.2.1, here is an algorithm:

1. Enable Developer Mode on your device as advised here: [XCode does not show my iPhone as a destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73711213/xcode-does-not-show-my-iphone-as-a-destination)

If your Xcode version is current enough, that's all you should need, skip to step 4.

2. Download iOS 16.0 device support files. One of the resources could be found here: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport
3. Unzip the files and place the content into one of the following two destinations:

Variant1: Applications >> Xcode >> (via right click) Show Package Contents >> Contents >> Developer >> Platforms >> iPhoneOS.platform >> DeviceSupport

Variant2: YourUserName >> Library >> Developer >> Xcode >> iOS DeviceSupport

The choice of a variant is up to you, basically whichever works (in my case it is Variant2).

Additionally, make sure the name of the copied folder is "16.0", not simply "16".

4. Start Xcode, now it should be ready to build to your iPhone.

Comment: Initially I did not see the "Development Mode" option on my device. Research indicates that you need to give iOS 16 a hint that you want to use the device for development, otherwise the OS will not expose the option to protect the user from harm . One way how to achieve this apparently is to sideload an app onto the device, but this was unacceptable for me. So what I did was to manually create a Development Provisioning Profile on developer.apple.com and install that (via Xcode) on the device. With the profile installed iOS 16 immediately started to show the Development Mode option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly advise against downloading binaries from unverified Github repo. My suggestion would be to download Xcode 14 from apple , unpack it then copy the device support folders (16.0, 16.1, 16.4, etc..) you need into your Xcode 13.2 installation:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

I couldn't find device support for 16.6 but so far it looks like cloning 16.4 and renaming it to 16.6 works too. It should be sufficient enough for deploying your app on device. Debugging is entirely broken though but then you could perhaps debug on iOS 15 device, that should work.