# XCode does not show my iPhone as a destination

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios16

When try to run my app on my iPhone with iOS 16, XCode does not show the phone as an option even though it is connected by USB.  This used to work.

I have tried rebooting XCode, my phone and my MacBook but nothing changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 16, you need to manually and explicitly enable Developer mode in Settings on your iPhone before you can use it for debugging with XCode.

Go to Settings -> Privacy and Security -> Developer Mode

For iOS 16 devices you must also have the following on your Mac:

- XCode 14+
- MacOS Monterey 12.6+

[image]

[image]

[image]